# Feasibility of converting all python pandas/numpy code to base python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**General python question-** 
I have built a script using numpy and pandas libraries. I have now been told that I cannot use any libraries- only base python to code. This is because apparently open source libraries are not approved.

1. Does this restriction make sense? Isn't base python as open source as pandas/numpy libraries are?
2. Is it possible to convert pandas/numpy code to base python? Does this sound like a simple exercise or does it require learning a lot of new functions? Majority of the code is reading tables and then using if/then type statements and looking up values from other tables to generate and populate new tables.

Comment: Yeah, if open source is restricted, you may as well drop python and do all your calculations by hand using pen and paper. Print out your CSV and make sure you have a lot of scratch paper at the ready 

Comment: That's the saddest thing I've ever heard. Why would yo not be able to use **open source** libraries? They've been highly optimized at a low level so reinventing the wheel would be completely terrible in performance in comparison and would take a ton of time to get a competent library

Comment: In my opinion, it does not make any sense to use python then, because this packages are supposed to help and not to make life harder. From what I know, there is no such construct like eg. DataFrame in base python (which pandas has). You should think now to switch to R (but again, it has also many open source packages - the whole thing is based on open source).

Comment: If you need to use base Python, focus on using lists and dictionaries, and modules like `csv`.  Don't try to imitate dataframes.

Comment: It is hard to argue for a general ban on open source libraries, from any point of view. It does make sense to restrict the types of open source licenses (e.g. GPL license requires open sourcing any linked code), but there really is no good reason to prevent usage of (good) open source libraries with licenses compatible with your environment (besides learning how to implement something and similar). Reimplementing NumPy/Pandas functionality yourself will probably be a huge amount of work with no real benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only going to address the 2nd point. Reimplementing all of numpy/pandas is certainly a *very* large and useless task. But you're not reimplementing all of it, you only need some parts, and if it's only a few functions, than it's certainly possible.

I'd start from a working script, replace arrays by python lists, and implement the needed fucntions one by one. For SO specifically, I suspect you're better off asking specific questions, e.g. *how to implement an analog of a function X in pure python* etc.